# About the ROC of deep leaning model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have made a deep neural network which classify such data, with a threshold of 0.5, it means if the incoming data is more than 0.5, the output is 1 and 0 else.

My question, is that graph is logic and is the choice of threshold 0.5 is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph seems to show the true positives (TP) and false negatives (FN) for different thresholds, not just for 0.5. There's no way to tell from that graph whether a threshold of 0.5 is a good value since we don't know the corresponding threshold values. Even if the values were shown in the graph, it still wouldn't be possible to say whether 0.5 is a good value, because it depends on the ratio of TP/FN you want for your application.

Comment: I got what you mean, thank you so much.  So based on the above graph, does it mean that my DNN model is performing well ? ..

Comment: Hard to say, it depends on the data.

Comment: I mean when the FN = 0.8 what does mean that TP = 1 ? does that mean when taking the threshold 0.8 the percentage of correct choice will be 100% ?  that's what I need to understand from the graph

Comment: No, that's not what that means. You might want to look into what true positives and false negatives are.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I see graphs for some models which are not smooth like mine!!  Is the issue in their graphs or in mine ?

Comment: Are you sure those are ROC curves and not loss graphs?

Comment: They are ROC graphs, for example as shown here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-classification-in-python/

Comment: Maybe you're using more datapoints.